# What is Byrnes-Isidori form and why is it usefu?

Tags: control-system, state-space, pole-zeroplot

I was reading a paper about analysis of "Zero Dynamics" of a system but they initially converted the state-space model of the system into a "Byrnes-Isidori normal" form. What is that and why not just use state space model for zero dynamic analysis?